# Design modules in NestJS application

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs, backend

I'm working on a NestJS application where I have an `Auth` module responsible for user authentication. Within this module, I have a `UserService` provider, which serves as a kind of repository for database operations. It contains functions like `findById`, `findByEmail`, `addUser`, etc., which execute database queries.

Apart from that, there is an `AuthProvider` within the `Auth` module, responsible for authentication logic.

I'm wondering if it makes sense to create a separate `Users` module specifically for the `UserService` as a repository and then import this module wherever it's needed. This would keep the user-related functionality isolated in its own module.

Considering that in the future, I will be creating a `Data` module, which will contain endpoints for retrieving various types of data, and it will also need to utilize the `UserService` to fetch specific user-related data, does this approach make sense for maintainability and scalability?

Is this module structure a good practice in NestJS, or should I consider a different approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a separate Users module for your UserService can be a good practice for maintainability and scalability, especially if you anticipate that user-related functionality will be used in multiple parts of your application (such as in the auth module, or data module in the future). This modular approach aligns with NestJS's emphasis on organizing your code into smaller, more manageable pieces.

Here's how you can structure your modules:

1. **Auth Module**: Continue to keep your authentication logic within the Auth module. This module should handle user login, and other authentication-related tasks.
2. **Users Module**: Create a Users module specifically for user-related functionality. This module should contain the UserService provider and any other user-related controllers, services, and DTOs. you can structure it like this:

   ```
   users/
   ├── dto/
   │   └── user.dto.ts
   ├── users.module.ts
   ├── users.service.ts
   └── users.controller.ts
   ```

   In the `users.module.ts` file, you can export the UserService as a provider, making it available for injection in other modules.
3. **Data Module**: As you mentioned, when you create the Data module for retrieving various types of data, you can easily import the UsersModule there to utilize the UserService when fetching user-related data. This keeps the code organized and ensures that you don't duplicate the user-related functionality.
4. **Other Modules**: If you have additional modules in your application, you can import the UsersModule into them as needed, allowing you to use the UserService wherever necessary.

By structuring your application in this way, you achieve: Modularity, Reusability, Scalability, Testing abilities

- **Modularity**: Each module has a clear responsibility, making the codebase easier to understand and maintain.
- **Reusability**: You can easily reuse the UserService in multiple parts of your application without duplicating code.
- **Scalability**: As your application grows, you can add more functionality to the UsersModule and DataModule as needed, keeping your codebase organized and maintainable.
- **Testing**: With modular code, it's also easier to write unit tests for individual modules, promoting code quality and reliability.

Overall, creating a separate Users module for your UserService aligns with good practices in NestJS and can help you maintain a clean and organized codebase as your application evolves.

Comment: Thank you for your comprehensive and insightful response!

At this moment I don't want to create UserController. Is it a good approach to create a module without any controllers (only with previously mentioned UserService)?

Comment: if you dont have any use with the `UserController` so dont create one, thats ok.